# Validating HTML Drop-down menu with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I'm trying to validate a login script, pretty much everything else is done but I don't know how to do a drop-down menu. How would I validate it, to ensure an option other than the default is selected, through JavaScript?

All of the other validation is done via a separate .js sheet, so I'm not sure if document.getElementById works or I'm just making silly mistakes?

HTML (Form ID is "registration_form"):

```
<select class="signup_input_styleV2" id="location" name="location">
    <option value="false" disabled selected>Region</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
    <option value"Oceania">Oceania</option>
    <option value"Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value"Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value"Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
</select>
```

Comment: whats the actual question?

Comment: How would I validate a dropdown form in javascript, to make sure something other than "false" or the default "Region" is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ( document.getElementsByName('location')[0].value == 'false' ){
    alert('Select something !');
}
```

This might suffice.

Comment: Can you use get elements by name when validating on another .js sheet though?

Comment: I think so, give it a try :)

Comment: why don't you use `id`? that will be unique. then use `document.getElementById`

Comment: For some reason, using ID always ran the "Select something" alert?
But Flink's answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `getElementById`

```js
function validate(){
    var val = document.getElementById("location").value
    console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<select class="signup_input_styleV2" id="location" name="location">
    <option value="false" disabled selected>Region</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
    <option value"Oceania">Oceania</option>
    <option value"Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value"Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value"Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onClick="return validate();">
```